# How can I map one to many when the mapping depends on values in two other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I need to add COUNT in temp DataFrame to a new column in final_df DataFrame based on corresponding COUNTRY and DATE. Date ranges from 1980 to 2016.

What would be the optimal way to do this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: please don't post images.  It is terribly inconvenient to attempt to answer your question when I cannot copy and paste data.  Rad these for guidance on how to post a question  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If my solution worked, you should mark it as correct, or otherwise say it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
final_df.merge(temp.reset_index(), on=['COUNTRY', 'DATE'])
```

Note that (I *think* you have to) call `reset_index` on `temp` for this to work properly, as you cannot refer to the index otherwise.